# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException on Decrypt File using AES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aes

What to do?

1.Encrypt File when uploading to S3

2. Decrypt File when downloading from S3

What I have did?

- Written code , to upload and download file from S3 - Working fine
- Written code , to encrypt the file , upload and download encrypted file - working fine
- Tried to write code which will decrypt the file when downloading for client , but I am getting

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple
>   of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

From above exception I understood that , there problem with size of array which i want do decrypt.

> I have checked , size of byte array after encryption and size of byte
>   array got from S3 object is different, But dont know how deal with
>   this.

Encrypt and Upload code

```
public void upload(FileItem itemFile , String keyName)
{
try{
     InputStream is = itemFile.getInputStream();

                 byte[] plain =  IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

                 String plaintxt = new String(plain, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                 final String base64Key = "ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==";
                 final String base64Iv = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==";

                 final byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Key);
                 final byte[] ivBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Iv);

                 byte[] encryptedBytes =   AES.encrypt(keyBytes, ivBytes, plaintxt.getBytes());

                System.out.println("Length of encrypted bytes "+ encryptedBytes.length);

                     s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(StorageServerProperties.S3_BUCKET_NAME_Audit_Server, keyName, new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedBytes), om));
                     s3client.setObjectAcl(StorageServerProperties.S3_BUCKET_NAME_Audit_Server, keyName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace()'
}
}
```

Code for decrypt

```
public void decrypt(String userName, String fileName)

    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(StorageServerProperties.credentials);
    S3Object file =    s3client.getObject(StorageServerProperties.S3_BUCKET_NAME_Storage_Server,userName+"/"+filename );


    byte[] cipherBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getObjectContent());
    String cipher = new String(cipherBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] cipherBytes1 = cipher.getBytes();

    System.out.println("Length in decryption 1 "+ cipherBytes.length);
    System.out.println("Length in decryption 1 "+ cipherBytes1.length);

    final String base64Key = "ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==";
    final String base64Iv = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==";

    final byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Key);
    final byte[] ivBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Iv);
    byte[] plainBytes = null;
    try {
    plainBytes =    AES.decrypt(keyBytes, ivBytes, cipher.getBytes());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know AWS provides option to encrypt and decrypt file using their api but I dont want to use their api.

For AES Encrypt and decrypt I am using

> AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

**Edit**

When I encrypt the data size is 22320 bytes.
When I get S3 object from S3 bucket and converts it into byte[] its size is 22314. i.e. 6 bytes are missing.

I can encrypt and decrypt the same file on local machine.(i.e. without s3 object)

Comment: Have you removed any newlines in the received data? That can mess things up

Comment: I have not removed any line from received data

Comment: The first thing to create s small (short data) test case. Next check is if the encryption works without writing the file to the S3. Next check that you get back exqactly what you send to S3. This process is called debugging.

Comment: @swapnil7 see if you receive additional newlines and delete them

Comment: @Yuri No I am not getting any newlines

Answer (score 0):

For decryption, you can write the code as below:

```
/* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(plaintext);
```

For a runnable example, you can go through [this link.](http://pastebin.com/YiwbCAW8)

Comment: I have checked the link , for decryption it need same object of AESEncrypter class

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear: "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: **Input length must be multiple of 16** when decrypting with padded cipher".

AES encryption is block based and for modes such as CBC the data must be a multiple of the block size (16-byted for AES). In the case the input data is not a multiple of the block size it must be padded, the typical option is PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5). Check that padding is the default option since it is not specified.

Check that the length sent to the server and returned from the server is the same length and that it is a multiple of the block size.

You can check encryption/decryption with the online [AES calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc) by Cryptomathic.

Comment: I can encrypt and decrypt the same file on my local machine therefore I think cipher option is not the problem. Yes , length sent and received are not matching , I think here is the problem and trying to find reason why they are not same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are stuck on an issue which needs further debugging and testing.

Let's walk through the following scenario:

**Basic up- and downloading:**

1. Create a simple text file (e.g. a few paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum)
2. Measure the file size, and upload it to S3.
3. Download the file from S3, check the filesize.
4. Is there a difference? Check via a tool such as S3Browser if the file is complete in the repo, to check if the upload failed, or the download failed.

**Basic encoding:**

1. Retry the **basic up- and downloading**, but this time encode the file using base64.
2. Is there a difference? Check if the encoding and decoding works without S3.
3. It works without S3, but not with? Probably something todo with the way you send data to S3 then. Check via Wireshark or some network sniffer what data is actually sent to S3.

**AES Encryption**

1. Now try **Basic encoding** using AES Encryption.

When you have done the steps above and are still stuck. Let us know with your findings, so we can better help you. So, also post snippets of code that **do** work as expected.